# что эффективней: srcset или .svg

Tags: html, css, svg, адаптивная-верстка, img

Есть набор изображений .jpg .png и одно .svg

что будет более эффективным:

```
<img src='./images/imgindex.png' srcset="./images/imgindex@2x.png 2x, ./images/{imgindex@3x.png 3x" alt=' ' width=33 height=33/>
```

или

```
<img src='./images/imgindex.svg' alt=' ' width=33 height=33/>
```

? ...ведь вектор будет сам масштабироваться без потери качества, но в том же размере и без доп. ресурсов.

может ли .svg заменять набор изображений для разных условий? или, можно/лучше как-то скомбинировать их?

Comment: конечно SVG лучше  ... меньше весит

Comment: вопрос интересный , для примера плотность пикселей играет роль не маленькую

Comment: @CodeGust, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Всё относительно!

Если ваш `SVG` состоит из тех же `PNG`, то без потери качества никак не обойдётся, поскольку `SVG` будет лишь внешне расширяем «без потери качества». Тогда это не выгодно.

Если же `SVG` создан без использования картинок `PNG`, то в этом случае он является более выгодным нежели `PNG`.